# Restore TeamCity projects from DB

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-5.1

Is there a possibility to restore the TeamCity project settings from an existing db?

I have separate servers for the TeamCity data tier and application tier.
The TeamCity application server had been damaged and i'm trying to restore it from the existing data tier.

I'm using TeamCity 5.1.2.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TeamCity project settings stored at [$TEAMCITY_DATA_PATH$](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD5/TeamCity+Data+Directory)/config folder. If you lost this folder there only one way to restore it - backups.

You can also review information on [TeamCity Data Backup](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD5/TeamCity+Data+Backup) to get more understanding on what data is stored in the database and what on the file system.