# Restore teamcity with just mysqldump backup of the DB?

Tags: linux, teamcity, teamcity-6

Lost `Teamcity 6.0` server but have a `mysqldump backup` of the Database that was taken during MySQL migration.

I'm not sure what can be restored with it yet, is the DB backup is any good?

Comment: Dumps/backups can be generated with different options; some do not include schema. Does your dumpfile include creating schema/tables?

Comment: yes it includes schema.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restore TeamCity projects from DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311639/restore-teamcity-projects-from-db)